# Error after installation of eclipse on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: eclipse, 16.10

I'm trying to install eclipse with eclipse's installer program. but getting a big error after I tried to run.

[image: error message]

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 4430031
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
```

{$ eclipse Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m' Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.}

Comment: How exactly did you install Eclipse? Could you please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1), run `eclipse` there and [edit] your question to include the output of that command? Thanks.

Comment: eclipse 
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: The "transcript" of the error message in the image differs wildly from the actual error message. How come? How did you create it?

Comment: I'll just post the same comment again: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.